# Need a new VM program, need to improve performance and other desirable features.

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I currently am using Microsoft Virtual PC 2007 to run my virtual machines. I have the .vhd and .vmc files for each VM.

I really want/need to get some better performance out of the VM's, I have done some reading and it seems Microsoft Virtual PC is really not the best VM program out there.

- Is there any program that lets me better control performance? (give it more ram, more processor time, monitoring & statistics?)
- I would also like to be able to easily drag a file from my machine to the VM, or at least keep my clipboard concurrent between the VM's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using VmWare Workstation 9, but before spending money, try Oracle Virtualbox.
If you're already using Windows 8, try the included Hyper-V-Features.

Also, take a look at your BIOS/EFI and enable the Virtualization feature (if possible).

Comment: I'll look at my BIOS, thank you (Evga Z77 FTW; updated BIOS too). I'm on windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

You mention the exact program that does all of these things in your tags:

> [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)

Your guest VMs may need "Virtualbox Guest Additions" for some of what you want, but Virtualbox will do all those things and many more.

Comment: Didn't realize that was a program. Thought it just referred to a virtual "box". I'll look into "VirtualBox" the program then.